# How do you iterate over float excel columns in python?

Tags: python, excel, file

Say I have an imported excel sheet that looks like this:

```
    A         B        C          D
4.296178, 0.434362, 0.033033, 2.758968
0.296178, 0.434362, 0.033033, 0.758968
3.396178, 0.434362, 0.033033, 1.758968
```

And I want to iterate through it in a way that returns the sum of each column, how would I do this?

I have tried this:

```
import openpyxl


    templist = []
    Col_one_total = []
    Col_two_total = []
    Col_three_total = []
    
    for row in sheet.rows:
        Col_one_total += row[0].value
        Col_two_total += row[1].value
        Col_three_total += row[2].value
        templist.append(Col_one_total)
        templist.append(Col_two_total)
        templist.append(Col_three_total)
        return max(templist)
```

but I keep getting an error saying `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Pandas to do this. The following code reads in the Excel file using the `read_excel` method and the sums each column using the `sum` dataframe method.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

column_sums = df.sum()

print(column_sums)
```

Output:

```
A    7.988534
B    1.303086
C    0.099099
D    5.276904
dtype: float64
```

Note: You need to have `openpyxl` installed for this to work. Else you'll run into the following error: `ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.`

Comment: I have typed this out but it has just outputted all the values in the column. And if I type df.sum(1) it just gives me the total for two of the columns, but not the others

Comment: I updated the answer to show the outputs. If you use `df.sum(axis=0)` you get the sum of each value inside the columns. If you use `df.sum(axis=1)` you get the sum of the elements inside each row.